# Understanding the type of out put from Musicbrainz cpan module?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference, musicbrainz

Im using the Musicbrainz cpan module to look up an album but Im having a few issues trying to decipher the output I recieve. I used data::Dumper to have a look at it, and it appears to be a hash or array of some sort but when I try to check the type I run into problems.

```
my $ws = WebService::MusicBrainz::Release->new();

my $response = $ws->search({ TITLE => 'ok computer' });


if (ref($response) eq "REF" || ref($response) eq "SCALAR" || ref($response) eq "ARRAY" || ref($response) eq "HASH" || ref($response) eq "CODE" || ref($response) eq "GLOBE")

 {
 print "\n What sort of thing is it? \n";
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a [WebService::MusicBrainz::Response](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WebService%3a%3aMusicBrainz%3a%3aResponse) object.

```
use WebService::MusicBrainz::Release;

my $ws = WebService::MusicBrainz::Release->new();
my $response = $ws->search({ TITLE => 'ok computer' });
my $release = $response->release(); # grab first one in the list
print $release->title(), " (", $release->type(), ") - ", $release->artist()->name(), "\n";
```

Comment: ok, thank you, but Im still unsure of how to use it. In the example given how would you get multiple results, rather than just the first one in the list?

Comment: I copied and pasted that from the documentation. Which I linked to. Which contains all the information for using the module. For example, the `release_list()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Like already said, it is a [WebService::MusicBrainz::Response](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WebService%3a%3aMusicBrainz%3a%3aResponse) object.
You can retrieve multiple results with accessing the release_list() which gives an array of [WebService::MusicBrainz::Response::Release](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WebService%3a%3aMusicBrainz%3a%3aResponse%3a%3aRelease) objects.

```
use WebService::MusicBrainz::Release;

my $ws = WebService::MusicBrainz::Release->new();
my $response = $ws->search({ TITLE => 'ok computer' });

my @releaselist = $response->release_list();
foreach my $release ( @releaselist ) {
  print $release->title(), " - ", $release->artist()->name(), "\n";
}
```

---

However, that perl module is somewhat unmaintained and the [XML Web service Version 1](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/XML_Web_Service/Version_1) it is using is deprecated.

You better use [Version 2](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/XML_Web_Service/Version_2) of the Web Service.
With [python-musicbrainzngs](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/) there is a python module available that uses the new (next generation scheme) Web Service.